# gnupg and gpgme lib version error on OSX

Tags: php, macos, gnupg, pecl, gpgme

I for heaven sake can't get gnupg installed on my OS Yosemite machine using pecl.

**Objective:**

Install gnupg module to be used in PHP to do PGP Encryption.

**Installed Stuff so Far:**

Installed gpgme using brew after installing autoconf. Neither brew nor autoconf was available on my machine. gpgme version installed is 1.6.0

Issue:

When I do `sudo pecl install gnupg` it tries to install it but quits at

```
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
```

I am pasting full log below.

```
sudo pecl install gnupg
Password:
downloading gnupg-1.3.6.tgz ...
Starting to download gnupg-1.3.6.tgz (19,273 bytes)
......done: 19,273 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJfzyjJ/gnupg-1.3.6
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for gnupg support... yes, shared
checking for gnupg files in default path... found in /usr/local/include
checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... no
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure' failed
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- I tried installing gnupg through brew command and it did installed fine but I can't use it in PHP.
- Tried manually compiling gnupg using `phpize` and `configure` but they trigger same error when I run `make` command.

Please tell me how I can fix this version issue.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install gnupg[2]` does not install `gpgme`, which is a library for interfacing GnuPG and offered in another homebrew package. Also run `brew install gpgme`. Afterwards, you should find the GPGME library under `/usr/local/include`.

Alternatively, if you install PHP through Homebrew, there are also GnuPG packages for PHP readily available:

```
$ brew search gnupg
gnupg
gnupg-pkcs11-scd
gnupg2                        
homebrew/php/php53-gnupg
homebrew/php/php55-gnupg
homebrew/versions/gnupg21     
homebrew/php/php54-gnupg
homebrew/php/php56-gnupg
```